# Как правильно передать json на сервер?

Tags: java, android, сервер

Я все делаю в `AsyncTask`. Нужно чтоб сервер получил `json` файл. Я не могу сейчас протестировать работает мой код или нет, поэтому решил спросить у опытных разработчиков будет ли отправляться `json` файл или просто уйдет как строка? и правильно ли я построил `URL` соединение? Материал который я смотрел показывают как принимать с сервера инфу я вроде все сделал так же только вместо Input сделал Output.

```
private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://israelr_lap:8000/appreg");
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();

                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();

                jo.put("deviceId", "123");
                jo.put("apiKey", SENDER_ID);
                jo.put("deviceToken", registrationId);
                jo.put("deviceType", "Android");
                jo.put("osVersion", osVersion);
                jo.put("appVerCode", versionCode);
                jo.put("appVer", versionName);

                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                bos.write(jo.toString().getBytes());


            } catch (JSONException | NameNotFoundException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    bos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: ну, как минимум, нужно указать метод запроса(`POST`, `GET`... или другой), `Content-type`, в каком виде данные отправляются(`json`, `xml` или что-нибудь еще)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://israelr_lap:8000/appreg");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();

            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();

            jo.put("deviceId", "123");
            jo.put("apiKey", SENDER_ID);
            jo.put("deviceToken", registrationId);
            jo.put("deviceType", "Android");
            jo.put("osVersion", osVersion);
            jo.put("appVerCode", versionCode);
            jo.put("appVer", versionName);

            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            bos.write(jo.toString().getBytes());

            String result = urlConnection.getResponseMessage();
            Log.d("", "server response: " + result); //проверить, что вернет сервер

        } catch (JSONException | NameNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                bos.flush(); //очищает поток output-a
                bos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        //return null;
    }
```

Comment: О спасибо! Нужно теперь потестировать. А еще скажите зачем нам нужно проверять, что вернет сервер? Что он может вернуть? Мы же я так понимаю отправляем ему файл и все, нам больше от него ничего не нужно... И может посоветуете какой нибудь ресурс где можно почитать про все это? Я знаю, что в инете много инфы просто может вы знаете что то что можно посоветовать?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, это не проверка, просто посмотреть, что возвращает сервер. К примеру, на сервере существует проверка на валидность данных, то он мог бы вернуть какое-то сообщение, что данные не валидны или что-то в этом духе, или же наоборот, что данные успешно обработаны.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, почитать на тему чего? отправки данных с помощью `HttpUrlConnection` или про `json` ?

Comment: О `HttpUrlConnection`. Я вот протестировал и мне показывает вот такую ошибку `java.net.UnknownHostException: host == null` если я правильно понимаю, то не может по какой то причине подключиться к `"http://israelr_lap:8000/appreg"` вот этому серверу? Наверное не правильно я как то подключаюсь...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, адрес сервера точно правильный?

Comment: Ну да... Я когда копирую его и на другом ноуте который в этой же сети вставляю в гугл, то открывается страница моего сервера...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, похоже, что сервер не доступен извне

Comment: а как можно проверить мой код на корректность? Если я поставлю другой адрес и посмотрю подключиться или нет, если подключиться то значит действительно проблема с сервером... Но тогда какой адрес поставить? У меня не другого... Вы не знаете как это можно протестировать?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, отправить запрос на какой-то другой сервер. Код рабочий, устройство не может достучаться к серверу.

Comment: Да я понимаю, что нужно попробовать отправить запрос на другой сервер, я так и написал в моем прошлом ответе. Проблема в том, что у меня нет другого сервера... Поэтому я и спросил может вы знаете как это можно сделать? Может есть какой то сайт-сервер на который можно отправить запрос? Я новичок в этом так что сорри если что то не то спрашиваю))

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, это вполне нормальный вопрос) Попробуй взять адрес сервера с туториала http://androiddocs.ru/parsing-json-poluchaem-i-razbiraem-json-s-vneshnego-resursa/ 
Но не забудь изменить парсер, чтобы корректные данные забирал

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, возможно, метод запроса будет другой

Comment: В итоге я запустил другой сервер, уже не локальный и попробовал ему отправить запрос... Вроде никаких ошибок не показывает, но к серверу ничего не доходит...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, в каком формате сервер принимает данные?(как это прописано в настройках) Что возвращает в качестве ответа? Как обрабатывает данные?

Comment: Все заработало) Спасибо!

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, что изменилось?

Comment: Как я писал выше, мы запустили нормальный сервер(не локальный), потом было несколько вопросов с его настройкой(я получал 403 forbidden), это означало, что не хватало прав или что то такое... Исправили на сервере это и все стало работать, я и отправляю и получаю ответ)

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, :)